# How to fix a conflict cause by my theme with Woocommerce and/or Gravity Forms?

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, forms, plugin-gravity-forms

1) I've tested that it is the theme that is the culprit as I have tried with all other themes and woocommerce forms and gravity forms look perfect.

2) It happens in my child theme but also in my parent theme. But not the demo. Theme is has the latest update installed. 
Theme is Listify by Astoundify. I have contacted them but they can't seem to figure it out plus they wait days before replying.

3) The issue is the appearance of the drop down menu arrow and the checkbox checkmark.

4) I have noticed with Woo, it doesn't happen with standard billing fields but happens if I either change the input type of a standard field and also happens when I create a completely new field with checkout field editor.

5) I have tried deleting woo completely and it still happens with Gravity Forms.

6) I have tried disabling all custom CSS but it still happens

7) Contact Form 7 looks perfectly fine and isn't affected.

8) dropdown arrow moves as the page size alters

[image: what it looks like]

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to answer this definitively as we do not have any php/html/css to look at. What I would do, generally speaking, would be to find the class or id of those fields. If they are unique to that field (i.e. not used anywhere else be either the theme or plugins) I would add custom CSS to get those drop downs correct.

If that is not possible, I would make sure I edit a Child Theme and change those template php pages directly by adding the custom css there to make sure this only affects the pages where these drop downs are "Wrong".

Just be sure you use a child theme, or all of your changes will revert when you update the theme.